# App unresponsive when javascript-profiling them

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ember.js, profiling, google-chrome-devtools

For a while I've been trying to run a JavaScript CPU profile of some applications I've developed, but everytime I start running the JavaScript CPU profiler in Chrome Dev tools, the application will stop responding at all (same as the profiler).

However, I noticed that this is not specific to my application, since I've been able to reproduce the same problem in other popular applications like Travis-CI.

I've been suspecting of extensions and plugins, but running without them doesn't seem to make a different -- the problem persists.

I've tested simpler apps with the same technology (the To-Do MVC example built in EmberJS) and that profile works just as fine.

I'm currently using Chrome 40.0.2214.111 m (64-bit).

Any idea on what the problem may be?

**Update:** I've tested both under incognito and guest browser mode. I thought the guest browser made a difference because I was able to profile my application once without problems. However, trying that again proved that the problem still persists.

Furthermore, I've found that the freezing time does not seem to be related with the application itself. Sometimes it'll hang when I focus an element, sometimes when I move around, some other times when I am in the middle of writing into a textbox. There seems to be nothing specific about the functionality of the app that's triggering this.

I've also tried disabling most extensions, without luck. I'll try disabling plugins as well and run as bare of a Chrome as possible.

**Update 2:** I've disabled all plugins and extensions completely, but the problem persists. I've also let the session go on to see if it eventually recovers. After around 2 hours, it was in the same situation. No bigger CPU consumption nor memory consumption, and other Chrome instances or tabs worked perfectly fine. I was able to close the developer tools but not interact with the original page anymore.

**Update 3:** I've just upgraded to Chrome 41 because it has been released in the stable branch, and I know it does include a few more things in the profiling section. I tried again and it didn't seem to make any difference.